# Two apps share one Redis. How to prevent cache collisions?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Two different versions of the application (debug and release) share same instance of Redis.
Both Debug and Release have identical source code and therefore identical caching keys for being stored in Redis.

[image]

Thus when Debug does `redis.StringSet(key1, value1)` Release could easily overwrite `key1` or read incorrect value (since it should have its own `key1`).

Is there a way to avoid such interference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two databases in the same Redis instance.
The [SELECT](https://redis.io/commands/select) instruction allows you to chose the instance to be used.
The number of the database may be given to your app by an environnement variable, so the code of the app remains the same for both application instances.

Comment: That's a recipe for disasters​ - use dedicated Redis instances instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Why would it be a recipe for a disaster?

Comment: Definitely - it just so happens that I wrote something about that :) https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances/

Comment: I'm not convinced by your demonstration. An infinite loop on a CPU intensive operation is a poor use of Redis, whatever the number of databases is, as it will block other clients. From a technical point of view, my answer is correct. However I definitely agree with the fact it's not a good practice to mix debug and release on the same instance, and that it could have an impact on production's instance performances.

Comment: The demonstration is synthetic, granted, but the fact remains that numbered databases share the same thread and can therefore block each other.

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer, The database thing is just what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @ItamarHaber: we agree on the conclusion.

Answer (score 10):

Do not do that - sharing is bad. Spin a Redis instance per environment, each server has negligible overhead.

Comment: upvote. never mess the production environment with debuging

Answer (score 1):

One another way is to give your keys a common naming pattern(prefix), and config the prefix in property files.

You can easily use different property files in different environment.